# I can’t install PWA by clicking on the button

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a React app. My task is to implement the installation of a PWA application by clicking on a button. Problem - beforeinstallprompt event does not fire. At the same time, when I go to the browser menu and select "add to desktop" - the application is installed.

I would be grateful for any ideas.

code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const styles = {
    width:'100px',
    height:'50px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    transform: 'translate(50%,50%)'
}

const Test = () => {
    const [supportsPWA, setSupportsPWA] = useState(false);
    const [promptInstall, setPromptInstall] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log('in use')// I see in the console
        const handler = e => {
            console.log('in handler') // I do not see in the console
            e.preventDefault();
            setSupportsPWA(true);
            setPromptInstall(e);
        };
        window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", handler);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("transitionend", handler);
        }, []);
        const onClick = e => {
            alert('click')
            e.preventDefault();
            if (promptInstall) {
                promptInstall.prompt();
            }else{
                    return;
            };
        };

        return (
            supportsPWA && (<button style={styles} onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>Install</button>)       
        )
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: try  `window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", handler(), false)`

Comment: Check the steps given here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs check if you have added manifest file.

Comment: @HagaiHarari  your option runs the function "handler" but event = undefined

Comment: @AkshayGohil Yes, I have all the files configured correctly

Comment: thank you all for your help

Comment: For the first few minutes of visiting my application, the button didn't work. Eventually, the button worked, without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved! I had second listener beforeinstallprompt

Comment: And what is the final solution? Please share

Comment: Yes if you could please share the final solution that would be much appreciated :)